Installing Numpy, Pandas etc. packages on PyCharm Community
I am trying to install Pandas, Numpy, Matplotlib on PyCharm Community. However, it says you have to upgrade to PyCharm Pro to access these? So, can anybody please explain whether I have to get the Professional version to access these libraries in PyCharm?
I have updated pip version. Installed all the packages in PyCharm with no issues reported. However, when I import them in coding it says not supported.

No need to get pro version...you can have all these...Please check Interpreter is correctly configured...File > Settings > Project > Python Interpreter

No need to get the pro version.
You can get all these items for free.
check Interpreter is correctly configured.
File > Settings > Project > Python Interpreter


Also you can install packages with the normal Python packaging installation guide and then point PyCharm to the interpreter you created with virtualenv command: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/

No need for pro. You can install these. I have installed PIL, OpenCV and Matplotlib on PyCharm Community Edition. Also, I have seen in the site-packages a lot more packages. Here are some simple blogs on installing these libraries. I have not tried Pandas.
Installing OpenCV, Installing Matplotlib, Installing PIL
